# Why does the accordion open upwards for mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, accordion

The accordion sometimes open upwards instead of downwards and the issue appears to be caused by the "flex-direction". This is a problem because the user has to scroll up to the see beginning part of the ".content" div.

The accordion is in the right container and has been set to appear above the left container with "flex-direction".

How do I get the accordion to always open downwards with "flex-direction"?

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("label");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function(){
   this.classList.toggle("active");
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
 }
}
```

```css
.stuff {
  background:#ebeef2;
  padding:1em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.left,
.right {
  width:100%;
}
.left {
  order:2;
  background:blue;
  padding:1em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.right {
  order:1;
  background:green;
  padding:1em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.label {
  font-size:2em;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.content {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  padding:1em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.content.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.label:after {
  content: '+';
  font-size: 32px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.label.active:after {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="stuff">In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed.</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left Side</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="label">Label 1</div>
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>
    
    <div class="label">Label 2</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
    
    <div class="label">Label 3</div>
    <div class="content">Content 3</div>
    
    <div class="label">Label 4</div>
    <div class="content">Content 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="stuff">In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the max-height to 100% on open won't actually animate the height change. For that to work with CSS, you need to set a precise value in a fixed unit, like 200px. This might cause jumping on the screen. Since jquery is already included, you might be better with [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions, @passatgt! I gave the ".content" a fixed height and implemented the .slideToggle(), but it's still opening upwards. I'm going to have to remove code to determine the issue.

Comment: Okay, I found the issue, but am not sure how to fix it -- changes are reflected in snippet. The issue is caused by the "flex-direction". Any ideas?